# How to make group runners I own pick up jobs faster?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I set up GitLab to use runners configured on my host. They pick up jobs which are in a specific group.

This works fine, except that the runners take some time to pick the jobs up. The first job is usually picked up quickly and the second one (sequential) takes some more time to be picked up.

This delay is acceptable but I would like to understand whether this is due to GitLab processing requests (in which case I will not have the ability to fine tune), or that this is something settable on the machine hosting the runners?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time is configurable on the runner using the `check_interval` parameter but [the default is 3 seconds](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-global-section) so that shouldn't be an issue, maybe you need to adjust the `concurrent` parameter so more jobs can run in parallel?